# VBA - Error when using ActiveCell and CurrentRegion

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a small piece of VBA that will shade a column of excel cells based on RGB variables in adjacent columns. So I have a table of data (no headings) with 3 columns (R G and B) and x rows (amount will vary). What I would like is to colour a 4th column to the right of this table in a colour based on the 3 numbers to the left.  Note that I plan to select the top left cell each time I perform this.

Below is the code I have used but I get an error message:

> Error 438... Object doesnt support this property or method

pointing to the `Set rng` line as being the problem.

Any thoughts or help much appreicated

```
Sub RGBTest()

Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Integer

Set rng = ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate

For n = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(rng.Cells(n, 1), rng.Cells(n, 2), rng.Cells(n, 3))

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So the line

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
```

causes the error `Error 438... Object doesnt support this property or method`.

That means either `ActiveSheet` doesn't support `.ActiveCell` or `ActiveCell` doesn't support `.CurrentRegion`.

`ActiveCell` is a range and [`CurrentRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is a property of `Range` so that shouldn't be it.

However, [`ActiveCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673.aspx) is not a property of a [worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841127.aspx) but of `Application`. That makes sense since there is only one active cell per Excel instance, not per sheet. So instead of

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
```

just use

```
Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Many thanks - seems to have helped.  But its given rise to the next problem.  I now get an error 13 type mismatch error on the line    "ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(rng.Cells(n, 1), rng.Cells(n, 2), rng.Cells(n, 3))"       Any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanHutchison maybe one of your cells doesn't contain a number.